# Why isn't the return type what I have coded here?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
Function<Function<Bill, Optional<?>>,Function<Bill, Optional<String>>> has =
            fn -> b -> fn.apply(b).isPresent()
                    ? emptyStrOpt.get()
                    : Optional.of("Missing");
```

A `Bill` may have a `Claim`. I'd like to do this:
`has.apply(toClaim)`

```
    static final Function<Bill,Optional<Claim>> toClaim = b -> Optional.ofNullable(b.getClaim());
```

The compiler doesn't like this:

```
Required type: Function <Bill,Optional<?>>

Provider: Function <Bill,Optional<Claim>>
```

I figure to get around this, I'd write something like this to cast the function I pass to Object:

```
    static <R> Function<Bill,Optional<Object>> generifyOutput(Function<Bill,Optional<R>> toX){
        return b -> toX.apply(b).map(x -> Optional.of((Object) x));
    }

static final Function<Function<Bill,Optional<Object>>,
            Function<String,
                    Function<Bill,Function<Bill,Optional<String>>>>> isPresent =
                        toX -> missingMsg -> b ->
                                toX.apply(b).isPresent()
                                        ? (Bill x) -> emptyStrOpt.get()
                                        : (Bill x) -> Optional.of(missingMsg);
```

Then call `isPresent.apply(generifyOutput(toClaim)).apply("No claim")`

But the compiler freaks out, saying that I'm providing `Function<Bill, ? extends Object>` instead of `Function<Bill,Optional<String>>`

Is there something else I can do here? I *could* just brute-force it like

```
Function<Bill,Optional<String>> hasClaim =
            b -> toClaim.apply(b).isPresent()
                ? emptyStrOpt.get()
                : Optional.of("No claim");
```

This seems a little ham-handed though, repeating the same logic for each nullable member of `Bill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make that `? extends Optional<?>` instead; `Optional<Claim>` is compatible with that.

Generics typing is **invariant**, meaning, only the exact thing matches, sub/supertype relationships do not apply. Because that's just how generics are defined. It is the right variance when both 'reads' and 'writes' can happen. Even in contexts where e.g. writes can't happen, the compiler doesn't know that, therefore, enforces invariance.

`? extends`  is java-ese for: I *want* covariance. Hence why this works.